# Allowing Users To Upload ANY File. Is My Method Insecure?

Tags: php

I'm creating a file sharing site, similar to Megaupload or Rapidshare. Just like those sites mentioned I need to allow ANY filetype.

I was thinking about a solution, and need to know if there is any security risks with it, or is there a better solution to my problem?

1. User uploads file
2. Check file size, if below 100mb begin upload
3. Encrypt the filename using IP, timestamp and salt
4. Store in a directory that is not accessible from the web
5. Store filename, description, and hashed file name in database

Upload done. Now for the downloading:

1. User requests download
2. Connect to database, locate file ID
3. If file ID found, copy the file from the file server location and prepare for file transfer

It's important to note that **NOTHING CAN EVER RUN ON THE SERVER**. So users can't upload malicious files and launch attacks on the server. When requesting the file, it will immediately launch a download, and never run.

Now, with the above in mind, is there any flaws in the model above that could allow malicious users to attack the servers?

For the purpose of answering the question, assume the rest of the site is secure.

Comment: If there's nothing that can actually try and execute the file that's been uploaded, then the answer is - yes, your model is secure.

Comment: @stereofrog why? Is there something here that PHP can't do, or can't do well? I don't see it really

Comment: @stereofrog *that* is indeed a problem, true. There are solutions to it though ([X-Sendfile](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/03/06/sending-files-better-apache-mod_xsendfile-and-php/) being one). Out of curiosity, do any of the other big scripting languages that can run on a Linux/Apache stack solve this in a better way? Perl/Python/Ruby? (If you happen to know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds fine, provided it is properly implemented of course; the only step that's missing IMO is checking for possible filename collisions between 3. and 4., and/or using a completely random file name. After all, the IP address and timestamp are not really relevant information in this context.

On the download side, copying the file on the server should not be necessary. Streaming it from the secret location should be enough, seeing as it will never be visible or accessible to the end user.

Comment: Collision between 3 and 4 is unlikely, but solution with  GUID and subdirectories based on first 2 characters (like git) would be better

Comment: @Konstantin agreed, collision is unlikely - but if an attacker knew how the hash is produced, there might be the  potential for overwriting somebody else's file by choosing a timestamp and IP  (though admittedly *extremely* unlikely and microscopic). There should be collision detection in any case.

Comment: This will not happen with GUID -  collision chances are the same as entire developer team eaten by wolfes (from git manual ;) )

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda just out of interest alone, do you have an example of using subdirectories based on first 2 characters. I'm not a git user. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It is known, that unix (and windows)  directories  have massive performance problems if there are too many entries  - common pattern is to take first 2 chars out of GUID,  and make sibdirecotry of it. This assures that there are not too much antries on each level. It is also possible to use more fine grained  directory segmenting